# JSF RequestContext is not beeing reset

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I got a Primefaces view consisting of a form and a remote command that fires every 100 ms (via Javascript).

```
<p:remoteCommand name="pollRemote" actionListener="#asyncJobManagerBean.execute}" oncomplete="handlePollMessage(xhr,status,args);" />
<h:outputScript>
   window.setInterval(function(){
        pollRemote();
    },100);

    function handlePollMessage(xhr,status,args) {
       console.log("request");
    }
</h:outputScript>
<h:form id="myForm">
...
```

The bean method called by the remote event does (simplified) the following:

```
if(somethingChanged) {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("myForm");
}
```

The idea is to update the form if the bean has changed, without any user interaction needed on the view. 
This works as expected, but even if `somethingChanged` is false, the form keeps updating. This happens as soon as the `update("myForm")"` was executed the first time. It seems like the RequestContext "remembers" that the form has been updated once, and keeps updating it over and over again.

How to make RequestContext to "forgett" the update when calling the next time?

Comment: My €0.02: Wrong take on things. Use PrimeFaces push instead of polling so often

Comment: I know, but it is implemented this crappy. I have to deal with it.